# kivy TextInput change font color add background lines

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am developping a simple Notes App. This is how my screen for adding a Note looks right now. [image: ![enter image description here]

I would like to achieve **two things**:

**1. Change the font color of my TextInput to white.**

**2. Add lines to my TextInput as seen in the picture**

[image]

The lines should always be visible even if the TextInput is empty.

Extract from my python script:

```
class NewNoteView(ModalView):
    pass
```

Extract from my kv file

```
<NewNoteView>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: 33/255, 41/255, 55/255
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            orientation: 'vertical'
            BoxLayout:
                Button:
                    size_hint_x:0.1
                    text: 'x'
                    font_size: self.height*0.5
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                    on_press: root.dismiss()
                Label:
                    text: 'New Label'

                Button:
                    size_hint_x:0.1
                    text:'+'
                    font_size: self.height*0.5
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                    on_press: app.root.notifyP()

                Button:
                    size_hint_x:0.1
                    text: 'L'
                    font_size: self.height*0.5
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

            BoxLayout:
                TextInput:
                    font_size: self.height*0.5
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                    cursor_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

                    hint_text: 'Heading'
                    multiline: False
                    padding_x: [30,30]

                Button:
                    size_hint_x: 0.2
        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: [38/255, 49/255, 70/255,1]
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            TextInput:
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                cursor_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                hint_text: 'Body'
                padding_x: [30,30]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very clearly structured (thanks!) but you didn't really do your research properly, did you? At least regarding the first question.

1. The answer is simple: use [foreground_color](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.foreground_color) attribute and set it to `1, 1, 1, 1`; from the docs:

> (fore_ground color is the) current color of the foreground, in (r, g,
>   b, a) format. Defaults to black.

2. Now this one is a bit more interesting and complicated. The straight-forward solution is to use the `Line` in your canvas. Something like this will add a white line to the bottom of the widget in the .kv file:

`canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
    Line:
        points: self.x + 20, self.y, self.x + self.width - 20, self.y
        width: 1`

And it looks like this when I changed your app to use two TextInputs:
[image: How it looks]

But, as I understand, you only want to have one TextInput in a note. So you have to figure out the line heights and draw a line every x pixels. [Here's](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.line_height) what I found. You need to either use minimum_height or line_height plus the line_spacing. Also, I don't think you can do this in .kv, I think you'll need to write a method for it in Python.

I would recommend using my method with extra TextInputs. You can bind "enter" to create a new TextInput every time so you can have infinite lines. I believe this will be easier, but you can do it either way.

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax in .kv file.
foreground_color:1,1,1,1